# remove edit link only for published post and pending post

Tags: functions, code

Currently i m using this shorocdes

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
if( get_post_type() === 'post' ) 
    unset( $actions['edit'] );
return $actions;
}
```

for removing edit link from published post but this code is applied on all post states and i want to apply this filter only for published and pending post. can any one help me to apply this filter only for published and pending post instead of All posts

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, where I changed the function to accept the [second parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/#parameters) which is the current post in the list table:

```php
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions, $post )
{
    if ( $post && 'post' === $post->post_type &&
        in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'publish', 'pending' ) )
    ) {
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Sally CJ. Your Code is correct and working smoothly.